# Implement recursion

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

The rules for this program are to:

- Generate n X n grid.
- Arbitrarily pick a point and grow a 'shape' based off that initial point.
- Must have at least 3 points.
- Strongly biased to not completely fill grid.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ShapeTestInConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Shape.Initialize(4, 4);
            Shape shape = new Shape();
            Draw(shape);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    private static void Draw(Shape shape)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < Shape.Width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < Shape.Height; y++)
            {
                Console.Write("|");
                Console.Write(" " + shape.ShapeDefinition[x, y].ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("|");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < Shape.Width * 5; i++)
                Console.Write("_");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
public class Shape
{
    private static readonly Random _random;

    private static readonly Tuple<int, int>[] _adjacent = new[]
        {
            Tuple.Create(0,-1),
            Tuple.Create(1,0),
            Tuple.Create(0,1),
            Tuple.Create(-1,0)
        };

    public byte[,] ShapeDefinition { get; private set; }

    public static int Width { get; private set; }
    public static int Height { get; private set; }

    static Shape()
    {
        _random = new Random();
    }

    public Shape()
    {
        ShapeDefinition = new byte[Width, Height];

        //Place seed point
        ShapeDefinition[_random.Next(0, Width), _random.Next(0, Height)] = 1;
        var activePoints = 1;

        var starts = new List<Point>();
        var neighbors = new List<Point>();
        var neighborsToActivate = new List<Point>();

        Build(starts, neighbors, neighborsToActivate, activePoints, 0, 1);

    }

    public static void Initialize(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    private void Build(List<Point> starts, List<Point> neighbors, List<Point> neighborsToActivate,
        int activePoints, int runCount, int currentLevel)
    {                    
        // Ditch if...  Has bias for 4 X 4 grid
        if (activePoints >= (Width * Height) || runCount > 5 || currentLevel >= 5)
            return;
        // minimum 3 points desired
        if (activePoints >= 3 && activePoints < 6)
        {
            if (_random.Next(0, 9) == 2)
                return;
        }
        else if (activePoints >= 6 && activePoints < 8)
        {
            if (_random.Next(0, 6) == 2)
                return;
        }
        else if (activePoints >= 8)
        {
            if (_random.Next(0, 5) == 2)
                return;
        }

        starts.Clear();
        // Gather points 
        for (var x = 0; x < ShapeDefinition.GetLength(0); x++)
            for (var y = 0; y < ShapeDefinition.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (ShapeDefinition[x,y] == currentLevel)
                    starts.Add(new Point(x,y));
            }

        neighbors.Clear();
        // with each start get adjacent usable point
        foreach (var currentStartPoint in starts)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _adjacent.Length; i++)
            {
                var neighborX = currentStartPoint.X + _adjacent[i].Item1;
                var neighborY = currentStartPoint.Y + _adjacent[i].Item2;

                if (InBounds(neighborX, neighborY))
                {
                    if (ShapeDefinition[neighborX, neighborY] == 0)
                        neighbors.Add(new Point(neighborX, neighborY));
                }
            }
            neighborsToActivate.Clear();
            // randomly pick which usable point(s) will be include with shape
            neighborsToActivate = neighbors.OrderBy(n => _random.Next())
                                           .Take(_random.Next(1, neighbors.Count + 1))
                                           .ToList();

            for (var j = 0; j < neighborsToActivate.Count; j++)
            {
                ShapeDefinition[neighborsToActivate[j].X, neighborsToActivate[j].Y] = (byte)(currentLevel + 1);
                activePoints++;
            }
        }

        runCount++;
        currentLevel++;
        Build(starts, neighbors, neighborsToActivate, activePoints, runCount, currentLevel);
    }

    private static bool InBounds(int x, int y)
    {
        return x >= 0 && x < Width &&
               y >= 0 && y < Height;
    }
}
}
```

This is a good facsimile of what I trying to accomplish now.  My own thoughts on improvements would be that Shape, for how I would like to use it, should not have methods to create itself and should instead be created by a ShapeFactory or ShapeBuilder class.  A Shape's only job is to be a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `runCount` and `CurrentLevel` seem redundant.
2. I don't see why you pass `start`, `neighbors` and `neighborsToActivate` as parameters to the recursive function since you just clear them without using the data.
3. `activePoint` might be better off being a member of Shape since that information might useful elsewhere too.
4. I would have made `Draw` a method of `Shape` since it is so closely associated with `Shape`.

You are now storing the shape as "active" points in a grid.  It would be possible also to store the shape as a list of points, e.g. {(2,3), (3,3), (3,4)}.   I'm not saying it is better here, but it might be a better option for some applications, especially if you have a very large grid with very few active points.